# Laravel Voyager: BelongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I have a table books and authors. I want to get the ability to attach authors to books. I tune BREAD for books:
[image]

With these settings I can click edit and choose authors for my book, but when I try to save books, laravel gives out this error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Mrs. Alivia 
 Stanton IV' for column 'authors_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into 
 `authors_books` (`authors_id`, `books_id`) values (Mrs. Alivia Stanton IV, 
 55))
```

And this is logical. But when I switch `name` to `id`, laravel  gives out this error:

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field 
 list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id` from `authors` inner join 
 `authors_books` on `authors`.`id` = `authors_books`.`authors_id` where 
  `authors_books`.`books_id` = 57) (View:
```

I tried to use all combinations, but nothing happened.

Model Books:

```
class Books extends Model
{   
protected $fillable = ['name','img'];

public function authors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Authors');
}

public function getImgAttribute($img)
{   
    if(!empty($img)){
        return 'storage/images/books/'.$img;
    }else{
        return 'storage/images/books/not-found.jpg';
    }
}

 }
```

Model Authors:

```
class Authors extends Model
 {

protected $fillable = ['name','img'];

public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Books');
}

public function getImgAttribute($img)
{   
    if(!empty($img)){
        return 'storage/images/authors/'.$img;
    }else{
        return 'storage/images/books/not-found.jpg';
    }
}
}
```

[image: Pivot table]
Help please!

Comment: Please provide your code when attaching the author to your books.

Comment: You need to specify the table when selecting the `id`, so it should be : `select 'authors.id' from 'authors' [...]`

Comment: @dexterb Models set up right, because site working normal, trouble in to voyager, but i m insert models code for u

Comment: can you include what method did you use to attach? because you can do `$author->books()->save($book)` and $author->books()->attach($book->id)`

Comment: Why do you use windows xp ?

Comment: @Jenssen This windows 7

Comment: can you show how your pivot table `authors_books` looks?

Comment: @dexterb yes, look up

Comment: *And this is logical. But when i switch name to id laravel gives out this error:* - can you also show your code on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model Books:**

```
class Books extends Model
{   
protected $fillable = ['name','img'];

public function authors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Author','Pivot table');
}

public function getImgAttribute($img)
{   
    if(!empty($img)){
        return 'storage/images/books/'.$img;
    }else{
        return 'storage/images/books/not-found.jpg';
    }
}

 }
```

**Model Authors:**

```
class Authors extends Model
 {

protected $fillable = ['name','img'];

public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book,'Pivot table');
}

public function getImgAttribute($img)
{   
    if(!empty($img)){
        return 'storage/images/authors/'.$img;
    }else{
        return 'storage/images/books/not-found.jpg';
    }
}
}
```

please read this document for better understanding http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: Really?I said: the site is working fine.According to the documentation: I can not specify a binding table, besides the code that you wrote does not work correctly, the second argument is a pivot table, not a field. please read this document for better understanding http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: NONAME i got it sorry for that. my  bad